Import a NFT from one marketplace to another marketplace
Hi: Here is my full smart contract and its work well except import a NFT from one marketplace to my marketplace like openasea/rarible to my marketplace. I have tried a lot but is does not work. Is there anything wrong in my contract from external NFT import. For external NFT I have created importNFT, importNFTWithNewCollection function as below
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    uint256 public commissionPercentage = 2; // 2% commission

    struct Offer {
        address offerer;
        uint256 offerAmount;
    }

    struct NFTDetails {
        uint256 tokenId;
        string tokenURI;
        uint256 price;
        address owner;
    }

    struct Collection {
        string name;
        string description;
        string backgroundImage; // New field for background image URL
        address creator;
        uint256[] nftIds;
    }

   struct ImportedNFT {
    address externalContract;
    uint256 externalTokenId;
    bool isImported;
}

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public itemPrices;
    mapping(uint256 => Offer) public offers;
    mapping(uint256 => address) public creators;
    mapping(uint256 => Collection) public collections;
    mapping(uint256 => ImportedNFT) public importedNFTs; // Internal ID mapped to ImportedNFT
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public externalToInternalMapping; // Map external contract and external tokenId to internal tokenId


    uint256 public collectionCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM")  {}

    function createCollection(string memory _name, string memory _description,string memory _backgroundImage) public returns (uint256) {
        collections[collectionCounter] = Collection({
            name: _name,
            description: _description,
            backgroundImage: _backgroundImage, // Set the background image URL
            creator: msg.sender,
            nftIds: new uint256[](0) 
        });
        return collectionCounter++;
    }

    function createNFT(string memory tokenURI, uint256 collectionId) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        creators[newItemId] = msg.sender;
        tokenCounter++;

        if (collectionId < collectionCounter) {
            collections[collectionId].nftIds.push(newItemId);
        }

        return newItemId;
    }

    function listItemForSale(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
        require(price > 0, "Price should be greater than zero");
        itemPrices[tokenId] = price;
    }

    function buyNFT(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint256 price = itemPrices[tokenId];
        address seller = ownerOf(tokenId);

        require(price > 0, "This item is not for sale");
        require(msg.value >= price, "Insufficient funds to buy this NFT");

        uint256 commission = (msg.value * commissionPercentage) / 100;
        uint256 sellerAmount = msg.value - commission;

        itemPrices[tokenId] = 0; // Remove from sale list
        delete offers[tokenId];

        _transfer(seller, msg.sender, tokenId);
        payable(owner()).transfer(commission);
        payable(seller).transfer(sellerAmount);

        
    }

    function makeOffer(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        require(itemPrices[tokenId] > 0, "This item is not for sale");
        require(msg.value > 0, "Offer amount should be greater than zero");

        Offer memory existingOffer = offers[tokenId];
        require(msg.value > existingOffer.offerAmount, "There is already a higher or equal offer");

        // Refund the previous offer
        if (existingOffer.offerAmount > 0) {
            payable(existingOffer.offerer).transfer(existingOffer.offerAmount);
        }

        // Update with the new offer
        offers[tokenId] = Offer(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function acceptOffer(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        require(offer.offerAmount > 0, "No offer made");

        uint256 commission = (offer.offerAmount * commissionPercentage) / 100;
        uint256 sellerAmount = offer.offerAmount - commission;

          itemPrices[tokenId] = 0;
        delete offers[tokenId];

        _transfer(msg.sender, offer.offerer, tokenId);
        payable(owner()).transfer(commission);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(sellerAmount);

        
    }

    function withdrawOffer(uint256 tokenId) public {
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        require(offer.offerer == msg.sender, "You did not make this offer");

       delete offers[tokenId];
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(offer.offerAmount);
        
    }

    function getMyNFTs() public view returns (NFTDetails[] memory owned, NFTDetails[] memory created, NFTDetails[] memory onSale) {
        uint256 totalSupply = tokenCounter;
        uint256 ownedCount;
        uint256 createdCount;
        uint256 onSaleCount;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            if (ownerOf(i) == msg.sender) ownedCount++;
            if (creators[i] == msg.sender) createdCount++;
            if (itemPrices[i] > 0 && ownerOf(i) == msg.sender) onSaleCount++;
        }

        owned = new NFTDetails[](ownedCount);
        created = new NFTDetails[](createdCount);
        onSale = new NFTDetails[](onSaleCount);

        uint256 ownedIndex;
        uint256 createdIndex;
        uint256 onSaleIndex;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            address nftOwner = ownerOf(i);
            if (nftOwner == msg.sender) {
                owned[ownedIndex++] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
            }
            if (creators[i] == msg.sender) {
                created[createdIndex++] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
            }
            if (itemPrices[i] > 0 && nftOwner == msg.sender) {
                onSale[onSaleIndex++] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], nftOwner);
            }
        }
        return (owned, created, onSale);
    }

    function getAllNFTs() public view returns (NFTDetails[] memory) {
        uint256 totalSupply = tokenCounter;
        NFTDetails[] memory allNFTs = new NFTDetails[](totalSupply);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalSupply; i++) {
            allNFTs[i] = NFTDetails(i, tokenURI(i), itemPrices[i], ownerOf(i));
        }

        return allNFTs;
    }

    function getOffer(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address offerer, uint256 offerAmount) {
        Offer memory offer = offers[tokenId];
        return (offer.offerer, offer.offerAmount);
    }

    function transferNFT(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner of this NFT");
        _transfer(msg.sender, to, tokenId);
    }

    function getCommissionRate() public view returns (uint256) {
        return commissionPercentage;
    }

    function setCommissionRate(uint256 _commissionRate) public onlyOwner {
        commissionPercentage = _commissionRate;
    }

    function isOwner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return account == owner();
    }

    function getCollectionsBasic(uint8 flag) public view returns (uint256[] memory collectionIds) {
        uint256 totalCollections = collectionCounter;
        uint256 collectionCount;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalCollections; i++) {
            if (flag == 1 && collections[i].creator == msg.sender) {
                collectionCount++;
            } else if (flag == 2) {
                collectionCount++;
            }
        }

        collectionIds = new uint256[](collectionCount);
        uint256 index;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalCollections; i++) {
            if (flag == 2 || (flag == 1 && collections[i].creator == msg.sender)) {
                collectionIds[index++] = i;
            }
        }

        return collectionIds;
    }

    function getCollectionAndNFTDetails(uint256 collectionId) public view returns (
        string memory name, 
        string memory description,
        string memory backgroundImage, 
        address creator, 
        uint256[] memory nftIds, 
        NFTDetails[] memory nfts
    ) {
        require(collectionId < collectionCounter, "Collection does not exist");

        Collection memory collection = collections[collectionId];
        NFTDetails[] memory nftDetailsArray = new NFTDetails[](collection.nftIds.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < collection.nftIds.length; i++) {
            uint256 nftId = collection.nftIds[i];
            nftDetailsArray[i] = NFTDetails(nftId, tokenURI(nftId), itemPrices[nftId], ownerOf(nftId));
        }

        return (
            collection.name, 
            collection.description,
            collection.backgroundImage, 
            collection.creator, 
            collection.nftIds, 
            nftDetailsArray
        );
    }

  function importNFT(
    address _externalNFTContract, 
    uint256 _externalTokenId,
    uint256 collectionId, 
    string memory _tokenURI 
    
) public returns (uint256) {
    ERC721 externalContract = ERC721(_externalNFTContract);
    
    // Ensure the user owns the external NFT
    require(externalContract.ownerOf(_externalTokenId) == msg.sender, "You do not own this external NFT");

    // Check if the NFT has already been imported
    uint256 existingInternalId = externalToInternalMapping[_externalNFTContract][_externalTokenId];
    require(existingInternalId == 0, "This external NFT is already imported");

    // Mint the internal representation of the imported NFT
    uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId); // Mint the new NFT to the user's wallet
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI); // Set the token URI for metadata

    // Mark as an imported NFT with the external contract address and token ID
    importedNFTs[newItemId] = ImportedNFT({
        externalContract: _externalNFTContract,
        externalTokenId: _externalTokenId,
        isImported: true
    });

    // Map the external NFT to the internal one (prevents duplicate imports)
    externalToInternalMapping[_externalNFTContract][_externalTokenId] = newItemId;

    // Add the new NFT to the specified collection (if collection exists)
    if (collectionId < collectionCounter) {
        collections[collectionId].nftIds.push(newItemId);
    }

    tokenCounter++;
    return newItemId; // Return the new internal token ID
}

// Add the functions for handling imported NFTs
function importNFTWithNewCollection(
    address externalContract, 
    uint256 externalTokenId, 
    string memory tokenURI, 
    string memory collectionName, 
    string memory collectionDescription,
    string memory collectionBackgroundImage
) public {
    // Create a new collection if needed
    uint256 newCollectionId = createCollection(collectionName, collectionDescription, collectionBackgroundImage);

    // Call the importNFT function to handle the NFT import
    importNFT(externalContract, externalTokenId, newCollectionId, tokenURI);
}

function getImportedNFT(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address externalContract, uint256 externalTokenId, bool isImported) {
    ImportedNFT memory nft = importedNFTs[tokenId];
    return (nft.externalContract, nft.externalTokenId, nft.isImported);
}

}


What error are you getting?

Actually I want to list for a Rarible NFT in my marketplace which owns by me. In my code I have written approve functions which approves to Rariable smart contract to grant access to my marketplace for this particular token id and always getting "Invalid tokeId" though token id is correct. In metamsk approve transaction is successful then how my marketplace smart contract is not getting this token id?

Done. I have changed the approach. I have done it morais API & standard ABI instead of fetch ABI for external contract address like approve/approve all.
